# How to check if two object are overlapping in a Canvas widget?

Tags: python, overlap, tkinter-canvas

Say I have objects within the Canvas with a tags `'stopped'` and `'flying'`.

How do I check if any of this objects overlap each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `find_overlapping`

```py
find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2) => tuple
```

> ```
> Returns a tuple of all items that overlap the given rectangle, or that are 
> completely enclosed by it.
> ```

And then loop through the result list looking for your tag.

Comment: Right! And then if tuple > 0, then something is overlapping!
Pardon my incompetence, how do I insert x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates from each of the tagged objects?

Comment: you can loop through your objects or tags and do a bbox. This will give you back the coordinates

Comment: works, thanks!
        falling = canvas.find_withtag('falling')
        stopped = canvas.find_withtag('stopped')
        for f in falling:
            for s in stopped:
                if (canvas.bbox(f)[3] == canvas.bbox(s)[1])and(canvas.bbox(f)[0] == canvas.bbox(s)[0]):
                    canvas.itemconfigure( 'falling' ,tag='stopped')